# MS teams: Easy way to get team/chat members?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is there any way to get the team members in a tab scope using the SDK? I know you can get them by using *Graph API*, it's just that I wonder if there's a faster way to get them. It would be very useful to apply some context to the info displayed on the tab.

And I've got the same question for *groupchat* scope. In fact, I can see a method called *getChatMembers*, but it's not working nor visible at the docs, so I suppose it's not deployed yet.

Nevertheless, in docs I can read:

> Because a malicious party run your content in a browser, this value
>   should be used only as a hint as to who the members are and never as
>   proof of membership

This kind of advise appears on several fields, so I suppose that using *Graph API* is safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Tab Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-context) you can get teamId, teamName, channelId etc. In order to get members in Tab you can use [/members Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_list_members). For Bot you can get the [team roaster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-context#fetching-the-team-roster) in bot context.

*getChatMembers* is not yet available for 3P apps. We are working on it.

Comment: I see that all the permissions on /members endpoint need admin approval. Is there another option to avoid requesting that approval? I would like to add contextual info to my tabs, but the admin approval might block users.

Comment: Is there a timeline on when `getChatMembers` will be available to 3rd party apps? This would help tremendously..